# Save locally generated PDF to app's documents folder in iOS8

Tags: pdf, ios8, uiwebview, nsdocumentdirectory, writetofile

It would seem that my apps no longer are able to save files to their documents folder when doing this:

```
        NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

        NSData *dta = [[NSData alloc] init];
        dta = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

        NSLog(@"writing file: %@", path);


        if ([dta writeToFile:path options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil] == NO) {
            NSLog(@"writeToFile error");

        }else {

            NSLog(@"Written: %@", path);
            [self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
        }
```

I do get "Written" in the log with the full path:
Written: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/ECBCD65D-A990-4758-A07F-ECE48E269278/Documents/9d440408-4758-4219-9c9c-12fe69cf82f2_pdf.pdf

And as long as I don't quit the app I can load the PDF in a UIWebView like this (pdfPath is a string that I pass to the function that loads the PDF file):

```
[www loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfPath]]];
```

Any help at all is as always greatly appreciated.

Comment: When I look at my log it seems the address after "/Application/" and before "/Documents/" keep changing. Would substringing from "/Documents/" do the trick? Seems a bit ugly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after mucking about I found that since the documents directory changes path every time I run the app, I had to:

1. Write the file to the documents folder with the complete path to
   the file:

   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask ,YES );
   NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: fileName];

   ```
   NSData *dta = [[NSData alloc] init];
   dta = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

   if ([dta writeToFile:path options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil] == NO) {
       NSLog(@"writeToFile error");

   }else {

       NSLog(@"Written: %@", path);
       [self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
   }
   ```
2. Save only the file name to my database
3. Load the file by using the full newly generated Documents directory path and append the file name from my database:

   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: pdfPath];